# English or French resume for Software jobs in Montreal?

Tags: resume, hiring-process, applications, canada, language

I'm applying for lots of jobs right now, one place I'm looking is Montreal. I'm seeing some job postings in English, some in French, some in both. Most or all jobs list being bilingual as a requirement.

When applying to software development jobs in Montreal, is it best to use an English resume, French one, or to include both versions?

I wasn't able to find any info on this online. Any advice from people who have lived/worked in Montreal would be appreciated.

EDIT: yes I'm comfortable in both languages.

Answer (score 7):

**Match the first language in the job ad**

I haven’t lived in Montreal, but I have interviewed for software jobs there. As a rule, a place seems to primarily English if the English comes first in the job ad. They didn’t ask if I spoke French. It always came up when the French came first.

Or, if you have solid proficiency in both languages, check which one is better written. The English on many where English was second was terrible. I don’t know a word of French so I can’t check the other side of this, but I suspect it would be considered “functional” rather than “fluent.”

Answer (score 5):

> *When applying to software development jobs in Montreal, is it best to use an English resume, French one, or to include both versions?*

- If you see the ad in other language than English,
- or the job posting mentions the requirement of knowing other languages that English

and you happen to be comfortable / proficient in that language, why not attach both the versions of your CV with the application?

You can mention the same in the cover letter (two versions), and name the CVs with "..._ English.pdf" and "..._ French.pdf" to avoid any confusion.

However, make sure you understand what is going into the CV. Don't just use a translator service to have the document translated and shared - the translation may not be accurate and might give a false impression of your proficiency. Do this only if you're proficient in the other language(s).

Comment: My kids are bi-lingual (well, tri...) and would never go near a translation service and neither would I. IMO anyone who can speak two languages well can do a better job or has an acquaintance who can help them polish it...

Comment: I speak French, and also have a few francophone friends I'd ask to read over my the French version of my resume.

Comment: @SolarMike right, the point I was trying to clarify is, only create the CV in another language if you are proficient in that language, not with the help of some random online translation.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso then it's OK. If in the interview someone wants to speak in French, at least you will be able to communicate and handle the scenario - fine.

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes I'd be fine interviewing in French, I just want to make sure I choose the right language(s) for my applications so I can make it that far